# Call stored procedures from another stored procedure or only one SP for better efficiency?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, processing-efficiency

I need to update 9 Tables. These tables should be updated by Stored Procedure.

There are pair of three dependent tables in a group. The rest of others (3 more tables) they don have any dependency.

Here is the question: 
It is more efficient to write **1** store procedure and update all tables 
or 
Write **9** SP 
or 
Write **6** SP (1 SP for each independent table and for group of dependent tables 1 SP for each then 1 SP to call all)

What is the best way?

Comment: as I know SQL server builds its locical tree collecting queries from every used source. So it will be just more correct to place it in different SPs just for future purposes. And to avoid doublecode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are updating 9 tables in one action like(button click),maintaining transaction may be your requirement ,so i would like to suggest you to make one storedprocedures and maintain transaction in it,rather than 9 different procedures..

Comment: First of all thanks for answer. Yes I have 9 tables and they should be updated after clicking that button. I need to have both sides, Performance and Maintenance. After putting all SPs in 1 stored procedure, it will be more than 500 lines. Therefore I wrote 9 for tables and 1 SP to execute all.